# YUI: Is there any any script made by using YUI, for slider.?

Tags: javascript, yui, javascript-framework

I m developing an application in YUI. And need to implement a slider for 3 forms.
which will work exactly like this JQuery Plugin :

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/

I am very noob in YUI.
So can anyone provide me code snippet for this kind of slider..?

Comment: There should be little problem as YUI uses namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

as mozillanerd suggests you can use the jquery Plugin in your page along with any YUI code you have, otherwise you might have to roll your own.  If you do put it up on the gallery so others can use it.

Comment: Sure... I will definitly post it at many places so that people will be able to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar widget in YUi i.e.  YUI 2.x Carousel widget

`http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_imagentext_source.html`

maybe this will fit in my scenario. I will try this and let u know guys..!!